# SilverStripe user friendly HTML value in summary_field

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a DataObject and GridField which, among other fields, holds a `HTMLText` datatype field. I wish to display a preview of this in the GridField, stripped from HTML.

**Non-ideal solution**

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Title' => 'Title',
    'Content.Summary' => 'Content'
);
```

Using `Content.Summary` nicely strips the HTML from the original value. However, the linebreaks are removed as well leaving all lines attached to eachother without a whitespace.

**How can I strip HTML, but leave linebreaks intact (still hiding the html 
 tag)?**

Comment: Do you have new-line character in your context, or <br> tag?

Answer (score 3):

To preserve 
 tags in the summary:

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Title' => 'Title',
    'ContentSummary' => 'Content'
);

private static $casting = array(
    'ContentSummary' => 'HTMLText'
);

public function getContentSummary() {
    $content = $this->dbObject('Content');
    $value = str_replace('<br>', '__br__', $content->getValue());
    $content->setValue($value);
    return str_replace('__br__', '<br>', $content->Summary());
}
```

Comment: My intention is to convert the HTML tag <br> to an actual linebreak. Is that possible?

Comment: By the way, the `$casting` causes a fatal error (unexpected arrow) so I removed it. Code still works, but <br> should be a real linebreak.

Comment: If your intent is to display the summary on html page, then actual linebreak will be treated as whitespace, but if you still want to do so, then just replace `'__br__'` to `"\n"` And I fixed typo in the `$casting` line.

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately it doesn't seem to convert it to an actual linebreak, it's a whitespace.